# Value already exist in mysql database and php

Tags: php, mysql, forms, isset

I have the code below to check on (a web registration form) whether the e-mail address is already exist in the db or not

It works good, it shows the e-mail already exist once i load the page. but it keeps process the form and input the same e-mail into the mysql database?

How can i stop the form from submitting if the e-mail address is already exist?

my code below:

```
$email = $_POST["email"];

$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email='$email'");

if(mysql_num_rows($query) != 0)
{
echo "email already exists";
}
```

Comment: Please make sure you sanitise your user inputs before using them in a SQL string http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection or better yet use parameterised queries with PDO http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php

Comment: What can we do to help you solve this issue (it remains unsolved for now...)???

Answer (score 1):

A good idea is to run an AJAX check prior to posting the form, ie in the client form verification state. Hence the user will know before posting the form that email is already added...

An AJAX solution would be:

On the FORM page, having an jQuery function similar to this:

Add jQuery with the validator plugin:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery.1.7.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery.validator.addMethod("emailunique",function(value){
  return eval($.ajax({
    url: 'phptocheckunique.php',
    data: "email="+value,
    type: 'post',
    async: false
  }).responseText);
}, 'Email address already exists, must be unique!');

$(function() {
   $('#yourform').validate();
});
</script>
```

Then in your form add the classes to the email input field:

```
<input type="text" name="email" value="" size="30" class="required email emailunique" />
```

Then make a separate PHP-script just for checking the DB (mail-address posted with $_POST['email'], similar to your above function (BUT SECURE!) that returns TRUE if there is an email already.

phptocheckunique.php:

```
<?php 
$dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$dbname", $user, $pass); 
$sth = $dbh->prepare("SELECT FROM users WHERE email = ?");
$sth->execute(mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email']));
if ($sth->rowCount() > 0):
   return true;
else:
   return false;
endif;
```

But if you still use your method, add an ELSE statement in the last if routine, then you will only add the person if email is unique... Also your code is very unsecure, you should consider using PDO.

Comment: Can you guide me to ajax example that i can look at please? what PDO means?

Comment: I voted for your answer, i didn't down voted for this someone else did. but i voted for it anyway. and i choose it as best answer. hope you are not mad. thank you.

Comment: @RubyBeginner Why not any more the "best answer"? Don't it work?

Answer (score 0):

You probably don't want to stop the form being submitted as such, but rather have the form submitted, run the check (as your code does) and if there is a match, redirect the user back to the form page along with an error message telling them the email address already exists.

That way the form will be submitted - but not processed into the database until the email address is unique.

To borrow from your code:

```
$email = $_POST["email"];
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email='$email'");
if(mysql_num_rows($query) != 0)
{
    echo "email already exists";
    // redirect back to form and populate with 
    // data that has already been entered by the user
}
else
{
    // insert form contents into the database.
}
```

On that note, your code is rather vulnerable to injection attacks. You should switch to PDO or mysqli prepared statements when processing form data like this.

Comment: the INSERT INTO  code is stored in the other page called insert.php and after the user hits the (submit button) it takes him to that page and the data will be inserted. now i have only the "email already exists and the whole php page or html not show up. this error message is showing once i load the page even when the form it empty?

Comment: It worked but i had to do it inside the insert.php page after the POST  method takes my form there to insert the data as all the codes live there. i tried do it inside the form page, it didn't work as it keept pointing to the insert.php even when it shows the user already exist or the e-mail. and that error message shows even when the form fields are empty after loading the page with another browser. now it works but i have to do it in the other page. what is the code to redirect the user back the register.php ? thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(mysql_num_rows($query) != 0)
{
echo "email already exists";
}
else
{
  mysql_query($ur_query);
}
```

Just put the "INSERT INTO ... " query for your database in the else part.

Answer (score 0):

you need to give like this,

```
if(isset($_POST["email"])
{
$email = $_POST["email"];

$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email='$email'");

if(mysql_num_rows($query) != 0)
{
echo "email already exists";
}
}
```

it will executes after you submit the form.

Comment: my insert code in the process or insert.php. in what page your code show be placed? in the registration form page or the insert.php page?

Comment: you need to give in registration page.then only the error message displayed in registration page. once the email is not exist then you have to insert record and redirect to other page.